# Converting Object to DatetimeIndex in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas, dataframe

I have an Index. Which I would like to convert to DatetimeIndex. The problem is that, the index collected from the database has a strange type. When I type

```
df.index.dtype
```

I get dtype('O'). I would like to convert all the indexes of that dataFrame to datetimeIndex. When I tried datetime.strptime function, It does not work. What seems to be the problem?

The data look like this

```
          e1      e2     e3
"01-12"   4       5      7
"04-10"   3       5      7
```

Comment: Is this `pandas`? if so try this: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.dtype)` also post what the values look like, they maybe strings

Comment: I have this error when I do that: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: you've not answered my first question, is this pandas?, also there was a typo, try this: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` also post raw input data and code

Comment: Yes it is pandas. I tried what you suggested but I still get the same error. The date I received is in this format: month-day .

Comment: try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m-%d)` however, I can only guess you're still failing to do what I ask which is to post raw data to show what your data actually looks like, I don't have a crystal ball. Edit your question to include the data

Comment: On your data I get this: `In [197]:
pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m-%d')
Out[197]:
DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-12', '1900-04-10'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)` which indicates it works

Comment: what's your pandas and numpy version?

Comment: my pandas version is pandas: 0.16.2 and my numpy version is  1.9.2

Comment: I don't know it should work, this works using pandas 0.17.1 for me